# How do I remove/fix that Expressionengine adds "index.php" in urls of template groups that has nothing to do with the index page

Tags: expressionengine

I'm having a weird issue with expressionengine. I have a website home page which i have created a template group for called "index". Inside index template group theres the index page template which works as expected, [www.domainname.com/](http://www.domainname.com/) goes to the index.php page.
What I have an issue with is if I add other template groups, those urls will look like this:

[www.domainname.com/index.php/template_group_name/template_file](http://www.domainname.com/index.php/template_group_name/template_file)

I'm not sure what am I doin wrong, as in their docs the url should look like this:
[www.domainname.com/template_group_name/template_file](http://www.domainname.com/template_group_name/template_file)

How do I remove that index.php from the domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it, it was hidden somewhere in their manual, anyone else having the same issue, paste the following in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

source:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/best-practices.html#removing-indexphp-from-your-urls

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fix this with your .htaccess file in the root of your public_html.

```
# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've added this to the htaccess, deleted the problematic template group, created a new one with a new name, checked the new file in that new group and I still get the same problem with the path having "index.php" in it before the template group. Any ideas?

Comment: found a solution, but thanks for the effort (answered above)